# Como establecer limites en la pantalla en el modo grafico del 8086 con FASM?

Tags: ensamblador

Necesito pintar una cuadrado que rebote por los limites de la pantalla aleatoriamente y cambie la direccion de la trayectoria con los direccionales del teclado.
Ya pinte la figura y la puedo mover en pantalla pero no se como crear limites para que la figura no se vaya de la pantalla y logre rebotar.

Asi tengo el codigo actualmente:

```
format binary as 'img'
org 7C00h

                cli                                            
                mov     ax,13h                                 
                int     10h

            @@: mov     ax,0x2401                               ; activar la línea A20
                int     0x15
                jc      @b

                lgdt    [gdtr]                                  ; Inicializar el registro de descriptores globales
                mov     eax,cr0
                or      al,1
                mov     cr0,eax                                 ; Activar el modo protegido
                jmp     8:protectedMode                         ; Inicializar el selector cs

        use32
        protectedMode:
                mov     ax,10h                                  ; inicializar los selectores de segmento
                mov     ds,ax
                mov     ss,ax

                mov     ecx,256*2                               ; "Colonizar" los primeros 2K de la RAM para
                xor     edi,edi                                 ; que sean la idt
                xor     eax,eax                                 ; La IDT comenzará en la dirección 0
            @@: mov     [edi],eax                               ; y tendrá 2K de tamaño: 256 entradas de 8byte
                add     edi,4
                loop    @b                                      ; Primero hacer que todas las entradas sean cero

                ; Configurar los PIC maestro(20h) y esclavo (A0)
                ; para mapear las irqs 0-15 con las interrupciones 32-47
                mov     al,0x11                                 ; Comando para cambio de irq base
                out     0x20,al                                 ; al PC maestro
                out     0xA0,al                                 ; y al esclavo

                mov     al,32                                   ; irq0->int32 (implica que la irq7 es la int39)
                out     0x21,al                                 ; para el maestro
                mov     al,40                                   ; irq8->int40 (implica que la irq15 es la int47)
                out     0xA1,al                                 ; para el esclavo

                mov     al,0x4                  
                out     0x21,al                                 ; ¿Quién es maestro?
                mov     al,0x2                  
                out     0xA1,al                                 ; ¿Y quién el esclavo?

                mov     al,1                                    ; Mismo modo de trabajo
                out     0x21,al                                 ; para los dos(modo 8086)
                out     0xA1,al                 

                xor     al,al                                   ; activar todas las interrupciones
                out     0x21,al                                 ; en el maestro
                out     0xA1,al                                 ; y el esclavo

                ; Luego ocupar los valores adecuados en la IDT:
                ; Este es el código que normalmente variará según la cantidad de interrupciones que
                ; deban utilizarse
                mov     eax,[irq0]                              ; Instalar la int 32 (irq0->timer)
                mov     [32*8],eax
                mov     eax,[irq0+4]
                mov     [32*8+4],eax

                lidt    [idtr]                                  ; actualizar el registro idtr
                sti                                             ; activar las interrupciones
                jmp     $


             timer:
                cli
                inc     [contador]
                cmp     [contador], 1
                jne     fin_timer
                                call Borrar                                       ; borrar la pantalla completa


        mov edi,[pos]
        mov [contador], 0
        call Figura
        cmp [variable],1
        je Adi1
        cmp [variable], 320
        je Adi320
        cmp [variable], -1
        je Adi01
        cmp [variable], -320
        je Adi0320
        cmp [variable], 319
        je Adi319
        cmp [variable], 321
        je Adi321
        cmp [variable], -319
        je Adi0319
        cmp [variable], -321
        je Adi0321
        Adi1:
        add [pos], 1
        jmp Limites
        Adi320:
        add [pos], 320
        jmp Limites
        Adi01:
        add [pos], -1
        jmp Limites
        Adi0320:
        add [pos], -320
        jmp Limites
        Adi319:
        add [pos], 319
        jmp Limites
        Adi321:
        add [pos], 321
        jmp Limites
        Adi0319:
        add [pos], -319
        jmp Limites
        Adi0321:
        add [pos], -321
        jmp Limites
        Limites:
        cmp [pos],51200                                           ; pararlo abajo
        jge MenorIgual
                cmp [pos],0
        jge MenorIgual1                                           ; pararlo arriba



            fin_timer:
                mov     al,20h
                out     20h,al
                sti
                iret
                                MenorIgual:
                cmp [pos], 51400
                jle Arriba1
                jmp fin_timer

                Arriba1:
                sub [pos], 320
                jmp fin_timer

                MenorIgual1:
                cmp [pos], 200
                jle Abajo1
                jmp fin_timer

                Abajo1:
                add [pos], 320
                jmp fin_timer
           align 4
           gdt:
                dq 0000000000000000h                            ; descriptor nulo
                dq 00cf9a000000ffffh                            ; código con máximos privilegios
                dq 00cf92000000ffffh                            ; datos con máximos privilegios
          .end:

          gdtr: dw (gdt.end-gdt)
                dd gdt

          irq0: dw timer and 0ffffh                             ; int 32 (IRQ0)
                dw 8
                db 0
                db 8eh
                dw timer shr 16

          idtr: dw 256*8                                        ; La IDT será de 2K de tamaño
                dd 0                                            ; y comienza al principio de la RAM

;Mis variables
           contador db 0 ;para contar 18 interrupciones que suceden en 1 segundo
               atributo db 0101011b ;el atributo lo pondremos a autoincrementarse para que genere diferentes colores de fondo y caracter
               largo dw 40 
               ancho dw 40 
               fila dw 80
               columna dw 128
               conteo db 4
               pos dd 320*80+128
               variable dw -1

;Mis subrutinas
         Figura:
        mov ah,[atributo]
        mov dx,[ancho]
      ciclo:
        mov cx,[largo]
      ciclo1:  mov [edi+0xa0000],ah
        inc edi
        loop ciclo1
        add edi,320
        mov bx,[largo]
        sub edi,ebx
        dec dx
        cmp dx,0
        jne ciclo
        ret
                 Borrar:
        mov edi,0xa0000
        mov cx,320*200
        mov ah,0
     @@:mov [edi],ah
        inc edi
        loop @b
     ret
         Izquierda:
         dec [pos]
         ret
         Derecha:
         inc [pos]
         ret
         Abajo:
         add [pos], 320
         ret
         Arriba:
         sub [pos], 320
         ret
         DiaAbajoDer:
         add [pos], 321
         ret
         DiaAbajoIzq:
         add [pos], 319
         ret
         DiaArribaDer:
         sub [pos], 319
         ret
         DiaArribaIzq:
         sub [pos], 321
         ret

                times 510-($-$$) db 0
                dw 0xaa55
```